# Use PDA account as shared Storage solana

Tags: javascript, rust, blockchain, solana, solana-web3js

My intent here is to have account that can store data to be used by program. I will be passing this account in every call I make to my onchain program. And if I try to call `allocate` from onchain, then it's results in `<pda-address>'s writable permission escalated`

It seems that having an PDA is good idea for this as only my program will be able to make use of it. But I am not sure how do I do it exactly. This is what I tried so far

- derive an PDA in front-end side
- Pass it as other normal account
- Program treat first AccountInfo received as PDA and use it to store data

Error with above approach:

- I need to allocate space to store data in PDA. But since PDA do not have Secret Key and for that reason no KeyPair, I can't call calls like allocateSpace.

What am I missing here? I am new to solana so I might have missed even a simplest thing.

**Client side**

```js
const deposit_instruction = new solana.TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [
            { pubkey: system_account, isSigner: false, isWriteable: false },
            { pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
            { pubkey: pdaAccount, isSigner: false, isWriteable: false },
            { pubkey: sender.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWriteable: true },
            { pubkey: receiver, isSigner: false, isWriteable: false },
        ],
        programId: programId,
        data: argument_ser,
    });

    return await callEntryPoint(deposit_instruction, [sender, payer]);
```

**Onchain program**

```rust
 let instruction = system_instruction::allocate(pda_account.key, 100u64);

        invoke_signed(
            &instruction,
            &[pda_account.clone(), system_account.clone()],
            &[&[SEED], &[&[bump]]],
        )?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this question (might be helpful for future readers),

There was nothing wrong in the way I structured flow. The problem was that I misspelled `isWriteable` it is supposed to be `isWritable`

It took me whole day to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Use `PublicKey.findProgramAddress` to get a program key and bump value. Send that to the instruction in your program.
Then within your program invoke the `system_instruction::create_account` to create the PDA with storage (up to 10k).

Comment: Thank you for help Frank. Question tho. Can't I `create_account` PDA from js? and also why shall I need to pass bump value?

Comment: you need the bump value if you are creating the account in your program.

Comment: Ohh thank you. But when I call `system_instruction::allocate` and pass SEED & Bump value in seed and `pda_account`, `system_account` in account_infos, it says: `<pda_address>'s permission escalated`. What I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you derived that PDA from your on-chain program.
2. In the on-chain program use `invoked_signed` instead of `invoked` to system_program.

Since that's PDA derived from your program, only your program can `sign` that PDA.

Comment: Regarding your point 1, Can't I derive PDA in client side with onchain program's public key

Comment: yes, in client you can  use `findProgramAddress` you derive any PDA from any on-chain program.  This on-chain program will be the only one could `sign`  that PDA.

Comment: I am also understanding same. But when I call `system_instruction::allocate` and pass SEED & Bump value in seed and `pda_account`, `system_account` in account_infos, it says: `<pda_address>'s permission escalated`. What I might be missing?

Comment: Are you call `system_instruction::allocate` from on-chain program?

Comment: Yeah. I have put example code chunk for better explanation. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's your `SEED `?

Comment: Currently seed returned is 244

Comment: SEED is what's you feed to `findProgramAddress`. Could you show the code of this part.